# How to scrape data from <script> element using Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape image urls from magento run site. Product photo urls are listed in

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": {"fullscreenzoom":"20","top":"","left":"","width":"","height":"","eventType":"hover","enabled":false},
                "data": [{"thumb":"https:\/\/example.com.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/7298259c5e8adb86380aac\/m\/a\/product-image-1.jpg",
                "img":"https:\/\/example.com.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/d86efc38c3706eb137091cd\/m\/a\/product-image-2.jpg",
                "full":"https:\/\/example.com.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/9222bce87e716be292\/m\/a\/product-image-3.jpg",
                "caption":"Product Title","position":"1","isMain":true,"type":"image","videoUrl":null},
                {"thumb":"https:\/\/example.com.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/7298259c41aa66380aac\/m\/a\/product-image-1.jpg",
                "img":"https:\/\/example.com.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/d86efc38c3706eb13bb117091cd\/m\/a\/product-image-2.jpg","full":"https:\/\/example.com.com\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/9222bce87e78616be292\/m\/a\/product-image-3.jpg",
                "caption":"Product 2 Title","position":"2","isMain":false,"type":"image","videoUrl":null},
...
```

What I want is the `full` values. I'm not Python guru, but I was able to get the inside of the script element into a `dict` object. Not sure if this is the right step or not, and how to proceed from there.

Any tips?

Comment: That is the right way to proceed. You can now obtain whatever you want from the dict object.

Comment: @CodeIt Cheers. I got it :)

Comment: Please, show the dict in your question.

Comment: @BasharAbdullah can you share how you were able to parse data from script with type "text/x-magento-init" because I'm having hard time trying to doing that. Thanks in advance.